# Appending to a cell value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sure there's an obvious answer here, but I'm stuck. This part in particular is throwing 424: Object Required. The really odd part, to me, is that it does successfully append 0s to the column, but then halts, and doesn't continue.

```
If cellLen < 9 Then
        Set C.Value = 0 & C.Value
End If
```

The rest of the code is below for clarity. In case it's not clear, this is the intended code flow:

1. Grabs named fields
2. Copies those columns to a new sheet
3. Renames them and deletes the original sheet
4. Creates some new sheets for use with a different script
5. Searches for missing leading 0s in a specific column
6. Adds them back in (this is the part the breaks)
7. Deletes rows where that specific column's cell value is 0
8. Pulls that cleaned-up column out to a new file and saves it

   ```
   Sub Cleanup_Mapwise_Import()

   Dim targetCols As Variant
   Dim replColNames As Variant
   Dim index As Integer
   Dim found As Range
   Dim counter As Integer
   Dim headerIndex As Integer
   Dim question As Integer
   Dim rowCount As Variant
   Dim colNum As Variant
   Dim colLetter As Variant
   Dim C As Range
   Dim cellLen As Integer


   ' Add or remove fields to be copied here

   targetCols = Array("gs_account_number", "gs_meter_number", "gs_amr_identification", _
                      "gs_amr_phase", "gs_city", "Name", "Phase", _
                      "gs_rate_schedule", "gs_service_address", _
                      "gs_service_map_location", "gs_service_number")

   ' Put the same fields from above in the desired order here, with the desired name

   replColNames = Array("Acct #", "Meter #", "AMR ID", "AMR Phase", "City", _
                        "Name", "Phase", "Rate", "Address", "Srv Map Loc", "Srv Num")

   counter = 1
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

   ' This counts the number of columns in the source array and sets the index to that value
   For index = LBound(targetCols) To UBound(targetCols)

       Set found = Rows("1:1").Find(targetCols(index), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

   ' This is basically an insertion sort, and ends up with the columns in A:K

       If Not found Is Nothing Then
           If found.Column <> counter Then
               found.EntireColumn.Cut
               Columns(counter).Insert shift:=xlToRight
               Application.CutCopyMode = False
           End If
           counter = counter + 1
       End If

   Next index

   ' There is a more dynamic way of doing this, using index
   ' As it is, replace A:K with the range of actual data
   ' PROTIP: targetCols is 1-indexed, and has 11 entries -->
   ' A:K encompasses that entire array -->
   ' Add/subtract 1 for each entry you add/remove

   Range("A:K").Cut
   Set TargetSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
   TargetSheet.Name = "Contributors"
   Range("A:K").Insert
   question = MsgBox("Do you want to delete the original sheet?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Sheet")
   If question = vbYes Then
       Sheets(1).Activate
       Sheets(1).Delete
   Else
       End If
   Sheets.Add.Name = "Data"
   Sheets("Contributors").Move After:=Sheets("Data")
   Sheets.Add.Name = "Graph"
   Sheets("Graph").Move After:=Sheets("Contributors")
   Sheets("Data").Activate
   Range("A1").Value = "Date/Time"
   Range("B1").Value = "kW"
   Range("C1").Value = "Amps"

   ' Yes, counter is 0-indexed here, and 1-indexed previously
   ' headerIndex does an absolute count of 0 To # targetCols, whereas index is relative
   ' If you change these, there is a non-zero chance that the For will throw an error

   counter = 0
   Sheets("Contributors").Activate
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
   For headerIndex = 0 To (UBound(targetCols) - LBound(targetCols))

       ActiveCell.Value = replColNames(counter)
       ' If you don't use a Range, it fits columns based on headers, which isn't large enough
       ' A1:Z500 is a big enough sample to prevent that
       ActiveCell.Range("A1:Z500").Columns.AutoFit
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
       counter = counter + 1

   Next headerIndex

   ' Find column number with meters numbers, then assign its corresponding letter value
   colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Meter #", Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
   colLetter = (Split(Cells(, colNum).Address, "$")(1))
   rowCount = Range(colLetter & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'Range(colLetter & "2:" & colLetter & rowCount).Select
   'Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
   'Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

   ' Meter numbers are 9 digits, so if one is shorter, assume a trimmed leading 0 and append it
   For Each C In Range(colLetter & "2:" & colLetter & rowCount).Cells
       ' If cell type isn't set to text, the 0s will be non-visible, which while not an issue for the CSV, is confusing
       ' Note that this does not persist, as CSVs have no way of saving Excel's formatting
       C.NumberFormat = "@"
       cellLen = Len(C.Value)
       If C.Value = "0" Or cellLen = 0 Then
           C.Delete shift:=xlUp
       End If
       If cellLen < 9 Then
           Set C.Value = 0 & C.Value
       End If
   Next C

   question = MsgBox("Do you want to create a CSV file with meter numbers for use with MDMS?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "MDMS File")
   If question = vbYes Then
       ' Call CopyMeters for use with MDMS
       Sheets("Contributors").Activate
       CopyMeters
   Else
       End If
   End Sub



   Sub CopyMeters()
   Dim index As Integer
   Dim fileSaveName As Variant
   Dim rowCount As Variant
   Dim colNum As Variant
   Dim colLetter As Variant
   Dim cellLen As Integer


   colNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Meter #", Range("A1:ZZ1"), 0)
   colLetter = (Split(Cells(, colNum).Address, "$")(1))
   rowCount = Range(colLetter & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   MsgBox ("Filename will automatically be appended with ""Meter List""")
   fileSaveName = Split(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".")
   fileSaveName = fileSaveName(LBound(fileSaveName)) & " Meter List"

   'For Each C In Range(colLetter & "2:" & colLetter & rowCount)
   '    C.NumberFormat = "@"
   '    cellLen = Len(C)
   '    If C.Value = "0" Or cellLen = 0 Then
   '        C.Delete shift:=xlUp
   '    End If
   '    If cellLen < 9 And cellLen <> 0 Then
   '        C.Value = "0" & C.Value
   '    End If
   'Next C

   Range(colLetter & "1:" & colLetter & rowCount).EntireColumn.Copy
   Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
   newBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

   Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
       SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
       ReplaceFormat:=False

   Selection.Columns.AutoFit
   newBook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is telling you that C is not an object.  Therefore, you do not need the Set statement.  Change your code to this:

```
If cellLen < 9 Then
   C.Value = 0 & C.Value
End If
```

Comment: OK... I swear to God I tried that previously, and was getting the same message, hence my confusion.

In any case thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change the numberformat on the range? Or use a function for the value? A function would be something like

```
Public Function FormatValues(ByVal Input as String) as String
    If Input <> vbNullString Then FormatValues = Format(Input, "000000000")
End Function
```

And it would be called like:

```
C.Value = FormatValues(C.Value)
```

But, if you're strictly interested in what the value looks like, and not as much as what the value is (since the leading zero will only be retained for strings) you could do something like this:

```
Public Sub FixFormats()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SomeSheet").Columns("A").NumberFormat = "000000000")
End Sub
```

This would format `Column` A of `Worksheet` "SomeSheet" to be of the format "0000000" which means numbers would look like "000000001", "000000002" so on so forth, regardless of whether something like "2" was actually entered.

Comment: I hadn't changed the format on the range because B2 contains "Meter #," which I didn't want formatted as Text, for some reason. Honestly none of it matters, as these are saved as CSVs, which strips out formatting - this is only so the leading 0 is added back in before being saved, and so it looks right while the user is using the spreadsheet.

Didn't use a function because I am by no means an accomplished coder, especially in VBA, and a For Each was working. I appreciate another way to tackle the problem, though.